# preg_replace on email template

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

i use swift mailer , and when i get an email from the server i get  this :

You request your password via Forget Password

Your username is : {myusername}

Your password is : {mypassword}

with { } , the function for send is :

```
function format_emailforget($info, $format){

    //set the root
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/email';

    //grab the template content
    $template = file_get_contents($root.'/forget_template.'.$format);

    //replace all the tags
    $template = preg_replace('{USERNAME}', $info['username'], $template);
    $template = preg_replace('{EMAIL}', $info['email'], $template);
    $template = preg_replace('{PASSWORD}', $info['password'], $template);
    $template = preg_replace('{SITEPATH}','http://smracer.com', $template);

    //return the html of the template
    return $template;

}
```

where is the bad think of this code ?

Comment: For one, you're not using `preg_replace` right. The pattern needs delimiters and `{` / `}` are special characters. Consult the docs for examples, or, as your template language is super-simple, just use `str_replace` instead.

Comment: thank you ceejayoz , i replace that and i recived without {} , btw @mario i put myusername because i thinked that was not relevante to put my username there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More elegant way and easy to maintain :)

```
$pattern     = array('/\{USERNAME\}/' , '/\{EMAIL\}/' , '/\{PASSWORD\}/' , '/\{SITEPATH\}/');
$replacement = array($info['username'], $info['email'], $info['password'], 'http://smracer.com');

$template = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $template);
```